# How to convert below JSON data to application/x-www-form-urlencoded?

Tags: javascript, json, x-www-form-urlencoded

I want to convert below JSON data to x-www-form-urlencoded format. How can do that in JavaScript? or else any online converter?

```
    stripe_data: {
          "type" : "card",
          "billing_details" : {
              "name" : "sample test",
              "email" : "sampletest@gmail.com",
              "phone" : "+61 76 253 4125",
              "address" : {
              "state" : "Melborne",
              "country" : "Australia"
              }
          },
          "card" : {
              "number" : "4242424242424242",
              "cvc" : "242",
              "exp_month" : "01",
              "exp_year" : "22"
          }
        }
```

I searched google but i didn't find any solution for this type of data (object into object).

Comment: `x-www-form-urlencoded` is a data format that only supports key=data pairs. There are extensions which support nested data structures, but not the core format. You should find out what, exactly, you are expected to send to whatever is trying to parse this data.

Comment: i want to send above data to stripe api `https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_methods` it's expect `x-www-form-urlencoded` format so that i want to convert.

Comment: You can stringify the request body and pass the header which is your intend to

Comment: How to stringify object into object data???

Comment: Are you using pure javaScript or some else framework? accordingly I can give prepared  solution

Comment: I am using nuxt.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved above problem using JavaScript package called `qs`.
I am working in Nuxt.js and using npm so i give answer through that point
First install using `npm run qs`
then in your code import qs like `import qs from 'qs'`
then use where ever you want like `qs.stringify(data)` // data - JSON format